# Easy way to set data protection flag on a file in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, data-protection

Currently I'm using a method to set the data protection attribute, that looks rather awkward to me. I'm wondering if there is a more direct way, instead of dealing with `NSString`, and `NSMutableDictionary`?
That's what I'm currently using (I know it could be optimized by "`using`" statements, but that's not what I'm after here):

```
public static void SetDataProtectionFor ( string sFileToProtect )
        {
            NSError oError = null;
            NSMutableDictionary oDic = null;

            try
            {

                oDic = new NSMutableDictionary ();
                oDic.Add ( new NSString ("NSFileProtectionKey"), new NSString ("NSFileProtectionComplete") );


                NSFileManager.DefaultManager.SetAttributes ( oDic, sFileToProtect, out oError );
                if ( oError != null )
                {
                    throw new DataProtectionGoneMissingException ();
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                throw new DataProtectionGoneMissingException ();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ( oDic != null )
                {
                    oDic.Dispose ();
                    oDic = null;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now ? not much. That's the Objective-C way and the MonoTouch (generated) bindings allows you to follow the same pattern.

You could avoid creating the `NSString` and use the ones provided by MonoTouch, e.g. '`NSFileManager.FileProtectionComplete` and `NSFileManager.FileProtectionKey`. That would avoid creating the two `NSString` instances many times (if your method is called multiple times, MonoTouch versions are lazily created and cached) and remove the possibility of typos.

So using C#3 syntax this would become:

```
NSMutableDictionary oDic = new NSMutableDictionary () {
    { NSFileManager.FileProtectionKey, NSFileManager.FileProtectionComplete }
};
```

Also we **try** to provide more C#-ish API to do the same job as `NSDictionary`. OTOH since there's a lot of API using `NSDictionary` for options we only have them (so far) for the most *common* ones.

*note: please feel free to file enhancement [bug reports](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) when you find cases where the API could be better*

E.g. based on similar cases (that were done before) this would/should ideally look like this:

```
var attr = new NSFileManagerAttribute ();
attr.ProtectionKey = NSFileManager.ProtectionComplete; // enum version
NSFileManager.DefaultManager.SetFileAttribute (sFileToProtect, attr);
```

It won't save much lines of code (at least for a single value) but it would make the source looks a lot better (IMO) and easier to use with code completion and avoid typos (over strings).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SetObject` rather than `Add` on the `NSMutableDictionary` to avoid having to create new `NSString`'s, but it doesn't really make *that* much of a difference to what you already have e.g.

```
var oDic = new NSMutableDictionary ();
oDic.SetObject ("NSFileProtectionComplete", "NSFileProtectionKey");
```

As far as I know, this is the only way of setting file attributes.